# Unable to Write Array of Dict to Plist File

Tags: ios, swift, plist, nsdocumentdirectory

I am unable to write array of dicts into plist file. I can write Dictionary to plist file is ok.

My code is as follows; It is always not success

```
    if var plistArray = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path)
    {

        plistArray.add(dict)

        let success = plistArray.write(toFile: path, atomically: true)

        if success
        {
            print("success")
        }
        else
        {
            print("not success")
        }

    }
```

What might be wrong?

BR,

Erdem

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. What types of objects does your dictionary contain? (plists can only contain a very short list of object types: arrays, dictionaries, strings, dates, ints/floats/doubles/bools, Data, and that's about it.)

Comment: @DuncanC it only includes primitive object type as you mentioned

Answer (score 4):

First of all **do not use `NSMutableArray` in Swift at all**, use native Swift `Array`.

Second of all don't use the Foundation methods to read and write Property List in Swift, use  `PropertyListSerialization`.

Finally Apple highly recommends to use the `URL` related API rather than `String` paths.

---

Assuming the array contains

```
[["name" : "foo", "id" : 1], ["name" : "bar", "id" : 2]]
```

use this code to append a new item

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    var array = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [[String:Any]]
    array.append(["name" : "baz", "id" : 3])
    let writeData = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: array, format: .xml, options:0)
    try writeData.write(to: url)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Consider to use the `Codable` protocol to be able to save property list compliant classes and structs to disk.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the serialization part, you need to convert your plist file to `data` first and then write to file.

```
 let pathForThePlistFile = "your plist path"
    // Extract the content of the file as NSData
    let data =  FileManager.default.contents(atPath: pathForThePlistFile)!
    // Convert the NSData to mutable array
    do{
        let array = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: PropertyListSerialization.MutabilityOptions.mutableContainersAndLeaves, format: nil) as! NSMutableArray
        array.add("Some Data")
        // Save to plist
        array.write(toFile: pathForThePlistFile, atomically: true)
    }catch{
        print("An error occurred while writing to plist")
    }
```